# Django template search bar

Tags: python, django

I am trying to connect a search bar with a view.py.
I already built the search urls.py, and I can enter the page by giving the path,
the code is like:

```py
path('.../search/<str:query>', ...),
```

So I can manually enter the page like `.../search/abc` if I am searching `abc`
But the model I built cannot use the Q function in Django.
Inside the `view.py`, I create the following code, and passes the query to the path

```py
def ....(request, query):
```

The problem is, I don't know how to build a search bar in template. The code I tried is:

```html
<form action=".../search/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Information</label>
    <input type = "search" method = "get" name = "get" placeholder="Search required">
    <button type = "submit">Search</button>
```

But after this, I got a link as `.../search/?get=` with the *query* at last. How can I get the path as `search/query`?

And the text I searched automatically changed the spaces   into pluses `+`, but it is `%20` if I type   in the URL bar

Comment: But how can I start querying by not using request.GET, my model cannot use those function

Comment: Oh I misundertood the question. Using `?get=` seems way easier, you can use  `unquote_plus` from `urllib` to deal with the `+` there. The approach you want doesnt have any straightforward solution. I can think of dynamically rewriting your form action by javascript with each keystroke in the search field, but that feels quite error prone.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the button into href onclick. I have to create my model directly from excel files which cols are dynamic. So I just load the data into as models. This brings me lots of problem